# HTML pages not AAD Authenticated

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

My website has AAD authentication enabled and it works fine when we try to access the home page.
But if I am accessing html pages directly, it is not prompting for authentication. Am I missing any setting to enable authentication for all the pages?

Comment: Maybe you're already authenticated? :)

Comment: :) - I tried in In-Private browsing to make sure I am not.

Comment: How did you enable AAD authentication? Is it in the site configuration? Then it should work for all pages, also static HTML pages. If it is as an ``[Authorize]`` attribute on some controllers, it will only apply to them.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have to set up your pages to request the user to be authenticated before it loads.

Here is me solving this problem with Python Flask:
[Refresh Tokens for Azure AD V2 Applications in Flask](http://shawntabrizi.com/aad/refresh-tokens-azure-ad-v2-applications-flask/)

> Now, in order to invoke this code at the right time, I need to create
>   a view decorator, and Flask has a sample for almost exactly what we
>   want to do here: a login required decorator.
>
> Basically, we add this decorator to any view where we expect the user
>   to be signed in. If the user has no token, we will redirect them to
>   the login page. If they have an expired token and a refresh token, we
>   will use the refresh token to get a new access token. Otherwise, if
>   the token is present and valid, we simply let the view load.

This same concept is available out of the box using .Net: [active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/blob/master/WebAppGraphAPI/Controllers/UsersController.cs#L22)

You can find in the README of this sample the following:

> If you want the user to be required to sign-in before they can see any
>   page of the app, then in the HomeController, decorate the
>   HomeController class with the [Authorize] attribute. If you leave this
>   out, the user will be able to see the home page of the app without
>   having to sign-in first, and can click the sign-in link on that page
>   to get signed in.